# Jobs email alerts don't know the difference between Cambridge, GB and Cambridge, MA

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs, email

If I [search for jobs near Cambridge](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=cambridge&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles+&type=Permanent&rs=1), the website understands that I mean the real Cambridge, not any of these newer towns in the US. I can see all the gossip about which local employers are hiring and what new start-ups there are. (And I find out about my employer posting job openings before I find out through our internal system!) But if I subscribe to email alerts for this search, all the results are about Cambridge, MA. Since the search doesn't have any keywords, just the location, that's a lot of irrelevant results.

Comment: I have a feeling this might be because when you're actively searching on the site the geo-ip lookup can kick in making the results more sensible. The email alerts are probably text based search only. I have a feeling  this is by design and more a feature request (I'm not a dev so don't quote me though!)

Comment: If the developers threat the location as text, then that's a bug, a place can have multiple names that are basicly the same location, but different texts if written as text

Comment: @JonClements your analysis is 100% correct!

Comment: @JonClements What you're saying is that the process of setting up the alert loses some information that was in the original query, producing behaviour that's surprising to the user and inconvenient. I don't see how that is anything other than a bug.

Answer (score 6):

When you search for jobs in "Cambridge" on Stack Overflow, we can determine accurately which Cambridge you're referring to because (since you're loading a page from the site) we have your current IP address, which we can use as a "hint".

In the case of job alerts, the job search performed to populate the email doesn't know about your IP address, hence we default to Cambridge, MA. That's [the default Cambridge](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Cambridge) returned by the Google Geocoding API in the absence of a region hint. I agree that Cambridge, UK should be the default, but here we defer to Google.

In order to address your problem, you can edit your job alert a change the location field from

```
Cambridge
```

to

```
Cambridge, UK
```

Comment: I already guessed that was the cause of the wrong behaviour, but the fact it works this way doesn't make it any less wrong. If you have to save extra information (the inferred location) when I turn on email alerts to make the emailed jobs match the jobs from the web interface, then you should do that. Trying to use the implementation as an excuse for the user-facing behaviour is poor form.

Comment: The default cambridge. You've heard it here first folks, there is now a default cambridge

Comment: @DanHulme It's not meant to be an excuse, just an explanation of the behavior. While that is not necessarily what you were looking for, that's the best answer I could give in a timely fashion. And yes, I agree we should make this better, marking as [tag:status-deferred]